# How to apply a hotfix to a specific previous version?

Tags: git, versioning, git-flow

I have read about gitflow branching model. Let's have a look at this examle:
https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/.

As you see currently we have 0.1 on master. This means that this code is on production and actively used by devs. What if some critical bug detected in version 0.1? How can apply a hotfix to that version only, cause lets say version 1.0 changed the api, and doesn't need it anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you could include the use of what is sometimes referred to as Support Branches.  These are probably documented in a few places, but the one place that I know that they are covered is here:

http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/git-branching-strategies/gitflow-examples/#support-branches

on the GitVersion documentation (NOTE: This tool is unrelated to this answer, I am merely pointing at their documentation on this topic).

Once you created a Support Branch for the version that you want to update, you would take a Hotfix Branch from that Support Branch, do the work to update it, and then merge back into the Support Branch, and then release from there.  If required, you could then also merge the Hotfix Branch into the develop branch, but this would depend on the fix.